# how to fix corrupted files windows8.1

Tags: windows-8.1

how to fix:

windows resource protetion found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them. details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.Log.  for example C:\windows\logs\CBS\CBS.log.

Note that logging is currently not supported in offline servicing scenarios

Comment: I assume that's output from sfc which means your component store is corrupt so use DISM to repair it

Comment: @Ramhound was referring to `dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`

Answer (score 0):

posted as answer for formatting...

To view the details that included in the CBS.Log file, you can copy the information to the Sfcdetails.txt file by using the Findstr command, and then view the details in the Sfcdetails.txt. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Open an elevated command prompt as described in the previous step 1.
2. At the command prompt, type the following command, and then press ENTER: `findstr /c:"[SR]" %windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log >"%userprofile%\Desktop\sfcdetails.txt"`
    **Note** The Sfcdetails.txt file contains details from every time that the System File Checker tool has been run on the computer. The file includes information about files that were not repaired by the System File Checker tool. Verify the date and time entries to determine the problem files that were found the last time that you ran the System File Checker tool.
3. Open the Sfcdetails.txt file from your desktop.
4. The Sfcdetails.txt file uses the following format: Date/Time SFC detail